# How to create a shortcode for my wrodpress website pages image hover container

Tags: shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYc2I.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gP2X.png)

Image Changing JS Snippet

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $ = jQuery;
//Image One
var ImgOne = "url(http://localhost/dg/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/Default_Board_game_cafe_good_mood_with_happy_people_paper_art_style_1_0_74ea811b-feea-4a1a-abde-8587dc3f28fe_1.jpg)";
//Image Two
var ImgTwo = "url(http://localhost/dg/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/Default_2_An_intricate_paper_art_style_illustration_of_London_Bri_0_92c685ac-526c-4b59-8f1b-83cf766741ce_1.jpg)";
    $(document).ready(function(){
        
    $('#card-one').hover(function(){
        $('#main-parent').css("background-image", ImgOne)
    }, function(){
        $('#main-parent').css("background-image", "")
    });
    
    $('#card-two').hover(function(){
        $('#main-parent').css("background-image", ImgTwo)
    }, function(){
        $('#main-parent').css("background-image", "")
    })
    
    
    })
</script>
```

Content Show/Hide CSS

```
selector{
    --text-position: -500px;
    --heading-position: -50px;
    --button-position: 70px;
}
selector, selector .single-card p, selector .single-card a, selector .single-card h2{
    transition: .5s all ease-in-out;
}
selector .single-card p, selector .single-card a{
    position: relative;
    bottom: var(--text-position);
}
selector .single-card a{
    transition: 0.5s all linear;
    position: relative;
    top: 500px;
}
selector .single-card:hover p, selector .single-card:hover a{
    bottom: 0px;
}
selector .single-card:hover a{
    top: var(--button-position);
}
selector .single-card h2{
    position: relative;
    bottom: var(--heading-position);
}
selector .single-card:hover h2{
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Now i want to create a short code for the image changing hover effect that i can use in another page or post .